# Problem with single quote in Bash

Tags: bash, quoting

I have a sh script for initializing dzen2, and I want to use Source Code Pro font to use there. Here's the code...

```bash
param="-p -dock -fn 'Source Code Pro-10'"

# the generated_output function is not important
generated_output | dzen2 $param
```

The problem is, the script doesn't work! dzen2 doesn't started...
After some search I found that the problem may occur because of some problem with single quote `'` or double quote `"` that I don't really understand...

I have tried using this:

```bash
param=$'-p -dock -fn \'Source Code Pro-10\''
# or something like this
param='-p -dock -fn '"'"'Source Code Pro-10'"'"
```

Still doesn't work...
What's wrong with this script?

Comment: Lots of details at [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep track of several separate strings (arguments) and later use them as separate strings, do not store them in the same string. Use an array instead:

```bash
param=(-p -dock -fn 'Source Code Pro-10')
generated_output | dzen2 "${param[@]}"
```

The quoted expansion `"${param[@]}"` will expand to the list of strings in the array `param`.  Note that this means that `Source Code Pro-10` will be a *single* argument, which is what you want.  If you forget the quotes around the expansion, the shell will continue to split each string on `$IFS` characters (space, tab, and newline by default) and then apply filename globbing to each generated word.

Your code relies on the shell to split the string `-p -dock -fn 'Source Code Pro-10'` into arguments for your command.  Since the shell splits on space, tab, and newline by default, this would result in the substring `'Source Code Pro-10'` turning into the separate arguments `'Source`, `Code`, and `Pro-10'` (note that the single quotes are also included in the string).

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)

---

In a `sh` script, you would instead use the list of positional parameters:

```bash
set -- -p -dock -fn 'Source Code Pro-10'
generated_output | dzen2 "$@"
```

This would also work in the `bash` shell.